# using a wildcard route, what to check for page number at the end

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a wild card route, but at the same time I want to check for the existance of a page number at the end of the url.

so my url might look like:

```
www.example.com/category/parentcat/childcat/234
```

where 234 is the page number.

the route currently looks like:

```
new Route("category/{*category}
```

Since its a wild card route, I can't put the page number at the end of the route definition.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionResult MyAction(string category)
{
page = category.Split('/').Last();
}
```

like this?

Comment: Indeed, once you use a wildcard route parameter segment it's up to the developer to do any additional parsing of the segments.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment on Alexander's post, a different solution to the general problem is to use a query string parameter for the page. In other words, the URLs would look like this:

`www.example.com/app/category/subcategory?page=123`

Then your action method would take two parameters:

```
public ActionResult ShowCategory(string category, int? page) {
    ...
}
```